# Internet facing user input form on SharePoint with profiles

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create an internet facing portal where external users can register and then fill in a web form.

```
Name
Age 
Date 
etc..
```

This info is then passed onto a database of some kind hosted in Sharepoint also. Then I want to have a search function that can query the database and return the results.

Is this something I can do with Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

if you're using office 365 you could utilize Microsoft forms which you could embed into a website and your users could fill the information and then it would populate into a SharePoint list.